# Can a linear solenoid be as efficient as a brushed motor with a gearbox?

Tags: motor, electromagnetism, solenoid

I've heard that linear solenoids are power-hungry and tend to overheat, especially if the stroke is long. Can a linear solenoid be as power efficient as a motor with a gearbox that converts rotary motion to reciprocating motion?

Answer (score 3):

The parts of a solenoid coil that are far away from the plunger at any given time will dissipate power, but won't impart much useful force.  If one had a solenoid with many short windings along its length, and at each moment only energized the ones that would do useful work, a solenoid could in theory be quite efficient.  Unfortunately, doing that would require having lots of discrete windings and control circuitry for them, which would be rather complicated.

A big advantage of a linear actuator driven by a rotary motor is that if a 3-pole motor would make 100 rotations during the actuator's course of travel, that would be analogous to subdividing a linear solenoid into 300 switched sections.  Putting 3 poles on a rotary motor, and then having a mechanism to turn 100 turns into a linear range of movement, is apt to be a lot cheaper than subdividing a coil into 300 separate pieces.

Answer (score 2):

The conventional work solenoid will never be as electrically efficient as a motor when each is adapted ideally to accomplishing the same work task. The simple reason is that the solenoid's own plunger mass must be accelerated to drive a load but then abruptly stops at the end of its travel, thus throwing away its kinetic energy. Also, the coil must then be turned off and its stored inductive energy is thrown away thru a coil suppressor or the spark across the switch. These two energy losses can easily be over 30% of the input electrical energy. This cycle continues until the task is completed. In contrast, a motor continues rotating thus conserving its kinetic energy and a solid state driver can conserve inductive energy during rotation,

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically yes, in general practice no.

The main problem with a solenoid is that it draws current while stationary. Efficiency is the ratio between useful output and input effort. Energy input is Volts x Amps x time, energy output is force x distance. When the solenoid is holding it consumes electrical energy, but doesn't produce any output. All the electrical energy is converted to heat in the resistance of the coil, so its efficiency is *zero*.

The basic principle of an electric motor and a solenoid is the same. Both use electro-magnetic attraction/repulsion to produce mechanical movement. In both devices a back-emf voltage is generated while the armature/rotor/slug is moving, which lowers voltage drop across across the coil's resistance and so reduces power loss. However the motor is constantly rotating so it does this continuously, while the solenoid only does it during the stroke. Like the solenoid, a geared motor has low efficiency when starting up or stalled. But once it gets up to speed its efficiency increases, and with a good gearbox it needs little to no power to hold its position.

But efficiency isn't everything. A geared motor is best when something must be moved over a long distance and/or for a long period of time. But absolute position is hard to control and it doesn't like being stalled. A solenoid may be better when you want a simple way to get short, quick movements between two well defined positions.

And there are ways to improve the efficiency of a solenoid.

1. Holding current can be reduced by switching a resistor in series with the coil once it has operated, or by pulsing it with a higher voltage during the stroke. Holding current can be reduced to zero by using a permanent magnet so the slug 'sticks' to the pole face when it is operated (you must then apply reverse current to release it).
2. During the stroke the solenoid builds up a magnetic field whose energy is converted to mechanical output, but the resistance of the coil wastes energy. To reduce this wastage the ratio of inductance to resistance should be large - but this requires a small airgap, which is incompatible with a long stroke. However if the slug and pole face are made conical then the airgap can be much smaller.
3. A load might only need to be 'kicked' by the solenoid, then it only needs to be pulsed for a short time so efficiency isn't as important. If the load is 'kicked' right at the end of the stroke then almost all the kinetic energy built up in the slug can be transferred to the load, and the efficiency could be quite high (perhaps even higher than a geared motor in the same situation).

Answer (score 0):

> Can a linear solenoid be as efficient as a brushed motor with a gearbox?

Only for a very proportion of cases.
A solenoid varies the air gap and magnetic force as it moves.
Depending on excitation and force profile needed and more it's usual to need to input more energy across much of the stroke to achieve a desired force or and or velocity profile.

If the application can be fitted to the solenoid characteristics then it MAY be very efficient - eg storing energy in an accelerating striker which then applies impulse to eg a pinball. You do not "care" too much about the way the striker arrives at the ball if the velocity is correct.

A motor is not 100% efficient (brushed or unbrushed) and a gearbox is mot 100% efficient but in most cases it's likely that you can get a better match to what's wanted than with a solenoid. In some cases if the solenoid is s good fit to the task then max motor and gearbox efficincies still cannot compete.

Why use a solenoid then? - The solenoid has the advantages of relatively low cost and size and you can put a brutally large amount of energy into a small low cost device in some cases. And not others.

Answer (score 0):

It's like comparing, say, gas engine and window mechanism efficiency. Brushless motors are efficient when they move. If you have an application where a brushless motor does exactly what solenoid does (moves certain load and then keeps some force without motion) it's efficiency will be just zero, because no work (F*dx = 0) is done- all energy is wasted.

In addition solenoids are driven by cheap and simple drivers. I mean, if you just control some simple device, you will not invest in high- tech current control circuit with tons of software behind it. You will only use like two- level PWM driver, and that's it. So you will use more current than required just to keep solenoid in place, which will heat it.

But if for any reason you want to make solenoid very efficient- just find appropriate application, use all motor driving stuff you can find, and it will be really fine.